# REST practices for 'read by natural key' operations

Tags: rest, jax-rs

Suppose we have an application that handles 'user' entities through RESTful web services. The user entity has a primary key and an associated 'read by primary key' web service:

- Primary key is 'id', associated reader is '**users/{id}**'

Now suppose the entity has several natural keys. What are the corresponding reader web services? Here is what I tend to use:

- Natural key 'social security number', reader '**users/bySsn/{ssn}**'
- Natural key 'email', reader '**users/byEmail/{email}**'
- Natural key 'first name + last name' assuming the pair is unique for example sake, reader '**users/byFirstNameAndLastName/{firstName}/{lastName}**'

I could have use finders instead, such as '**users?firstName=John&lastName=Doe**' but **I chose not to** because these finders do not have the same behavior than readers:

- They return a list instead of a single value
- They return an empty list instead of a 404
- They do not work so well with sub-resources such as 'users/bySsn/123456/address'

My question is: **what are the REST practices for 'read by natural key' operations?**

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't like all these `bySsn` and so on. Personally I'd use list filtering (yes, I know you didn't like it) or expose single endpoint `users/{id}/` that in place of ID accepts ID, SSN, EMAIL and whatever is needed. You can easily discriminate the ID you got using regex.